# Complex Query Incorrect Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, left-join

I have tried to search for a solution to this but I have not been able to find one that fits this situation.

First I must say that my SQL is a lot rusty. The following query is the most complex one I have ever done to date.

Here is the query:

```
Declare @root varchar(Max)
set @root = ''

Select 
    ib.irrnum, ib.status, pu.probtype, 
    ib.submitby, ta.[Task Action], ib.area, co.cost, 
    rc.rootcause, ib.jobnum
From
    tbl_irrbase ib
Left Join 
    tbl_cost co On ib.irrnum = co.irrnum
Left join 
    (Select Distinct probtype, irrnum 
     From tbl_probtype) pu On ib.irrnum = pu.irrnum
Left Join 
    (Select Distinct rootcause, irrnum 
     From tbl_rtcause) rc On ib.irrnum = rc.irrnum
Left Join 
    (Select TOP 1 
         (owner + Space(1) + Convert(varchar(10), senddate, 101) + Space(1) + taskitem) As 'Task Action', 
         irrnum 
     From 
         (select * From tbl_taskaction) ta 
     Order by 
         senddate Desc, sendtime Desc) ta On ib.irrnum = ta.irrnum
left Join 
    (Select [@root] = @root + rs.rootsource + Space(3), irrnum 
     From tbl_rtsource rs 
     Where rs.entrydate Between '10/04/2016' And '10/06/2016' 
     Select @root As 'Root Source') sr On ib.irrnum = sr.irrnum
Where 
    ib.submitedate between '09/28/2016' And '10/05/2016'
```

My problem is with the last Left Join line. If I take the entire Select statement out and run it in SSMS it runs fine, no errors. But when I try and run it in this query I get an error, red squiggly line under 'Select @root As' telling me the following:

> Incorrect Syntax near 'Select'.
>   Expecting ')', EXCEPT, or UNION

I do not know how to fix this. If I remove this last 'Left Join' line the query runs fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Basically, the last part of the join `SELECT @root AS 'Root Source' ` is a completely separate query and you can't have two queries in a derived table like this, unless you are using union. This whole join, `sr`, doesn't appear to be used by the rest of the query. What is its purpose?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Sorry this for sql-server 2008R2. So Aron you are saying that I need to Union the two queries in the Last Left Join line?  And i know that I am not using the variable because I could not get the query to run. Once i get it to run then i add the data to the select statement.

Comment: `Select [@root] = @root + ` is asking for trouble. Why on Earth would you want to alias your field same as variable syntax? And yes, you need to `union` those together, otherwise they are completely separate statements.

Comment: Building a string from the same column in a table based on certain criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the last `LEFT JOIN`, try something like this:

```
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT (
        SELECT rs.rootsource + Space(3)
        From tbl_rtsource rs 
        Where rs.entrydate Between '10/04/2016' And '10/06/2016' 
        AND rs.irrnum=ib.irrnum
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS rootsource
) sr
```

Then include `sr.rootsource` in the columns of the first `SELECT`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thank you for the example. it is working now.